# How to force the uniformly distributed numerical tick marks on the horizontal axis x in Excel graph

Tags: excel, graph, axis

I have the table with 2 rows, for simplicity

1 (should define horizontal axis):
0   0.03217 0.04119 0.09613 0.14178 0.17035 0.18824

2 (should define vertical axis):
86  81  80.8    73.8    69  65  63

I need to build a graph (line chart) with row No. 1 as horizontal axis and row No. 2 as vertical axis. The tick marks on the horizontal axis should be 0, 0.02, 0.04 and so forth.
So I select the data for horizontal axis from row 1 and the data for vertical axis from row 2.

However,  when I try to format the X axis I do not get the options for any numerical formatting.  The options start from Interval between tick marks and so forth. 
The options for the vertical axis are completely fine
What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to plot a line that connects your points (0,86), (0.0321,81) .... You should try using a scatter plot graph instead of a line chart.

Comment: Thank you for the scatter plot suggestion - this helped!